# Editing a line in a text file without using pointers?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to edit a line of a text file (.Hex file) containing all Hex characters without using pointers and in a more efficient way.

It takes so long because the program I have to edit some (around 30x4 bytes or 30  float values from the address values of hex file).

Every time the program replaces one byte, it searches the complete file and replaces the values, and copy back back again the new file to another file. This process repeats 30 times, which is quite time consuming and hence not looks appropriate.

What would be the most efficient method?

```
public static string putbyteinhexfile(int address, char data, string total)
{

    int temph, temphl, tempht;
    ushort checksum = 0;
    string output = null, hexa = null;
    StreamReader hex;
    RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser;
    reg = reg.OpenSubKey("Software\\Calibratortest");
    hex = new StreamReader(((string)reg.GetValue("Select Input Hex File")));
    StreamReader map = new StreamReader((string)reg.GetValue("Select Linker Map File"));
    while ((output = hex.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        checksum = 0;
        temph = Convert.ToInt16(("0x" + output.Substring(3, 4)), 16);
        temphl = Convert.ToInt16(("0x" + output.Substring(1, 2)), 16);
        tempht = Convert.ToInt16(("0x" + output.Substring(7, 2)), 16);
        if (address >= temph && 
            address < temph + temphl && 
            tempht == 0)
        {
            output = output.Remove((address - temph) * 2 + 9, 2);
            output = output.Insert((address - temph) * 2 + 9, 
                     String.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToInt16(data)));

            for (int i = 1; i < (output.Length - 1) / 2; i++)
                checksum += (ushort)Convert.ToUInt16(output.Substring((i * 2) - 1, 2), 16);

            hexa = ((~checksum + 1).ToString("x8")).ToUpper();
            output = output.Remove(temphl * 2 + 9, 2);
            output = output.Insert(temphl * 2 + 9, 
                                   hexa.Substring(hexa.Length - 2, 2));
            break;
        }
        else total = total + output + '\r' + '\n';
    }

    hex.Close();
    map.Close();

    return total;
}
```

Comment: @Asad: post your code, it'll be much faster to get help that you can use right away.

Comment: @Asad, you assign to the output variable before your "break;" out of the loop.  Yet you do nothing with the assignment to the "output" variable after you finish the loop, therefore those assignments are not accomplishing anything -- ever.  What is your intent there?  Are you actually trying to modify the file?  If so, the code you have will never do that, as you don't have an accompanying writer.

Comment: Oops sorry. Actually I am assging the complete file string in 'total' and return it to main program where I write this striong 'total' in a new hex file.
My intention was to make code efficient.And donot read all the file everytime. This break actually avoid reading the complete hex file once the desired line for editing is found. So after doing editing no need to read the rest of the file, rather replace another value in the file.

Comment: Why are you modifying `output` in the `if` branch if you're not using that value?

Comment: 1) FWIW, the initial 'Hex' phrasing was confusing to me - I thought it was a file with binary data in it and was going to suggest perhaps memory mapping it if you were going to change the contents in place (all bytes replaced in-place, nothing unchanged would move to a different offset).  2) IMHO, 78kb is pretty small, so barring a need otherwise, I'd suggest reading the file into memory, manipulating it as needed, and then writing it back out (same file, new file, whatever) when done.

Comment: Sorry output is actually need to be added with total in the if branch(I have make some changes for optimization try, nad forget to make all corrections ).
Still problem is same of consuming large time for producing output of midified hex file.

Comment: @James:Lets say i need to make changes in this line for two float values(means 8 bytes).And i am using readline() which read one line at a time so if the address of my first float  matches then i need to replace the value from this line,similarly if at nay other location of the program if i need to modifiy second float value whose address lies in the same mentioned line as before, then this scenario requires reading the whole file first for the first float nad then copy back.then after reading the whole file for secong float and copy back!!!!

:10700000418A57743BC5818E35478AC7AE9D9331FF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to massively rewrite your existing logic which does 'for each line, do this search and replace logic', I'd think the simplest change would be:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
foreach (change to make)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        // read values from line
        if (need_to_modify)
        {
            // whatever change logic you want here.
            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(...);
        }
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

Basically, you'll still do the logic you have now, except:

1. You read the file once instead of N times
2. you get rid of streamreader / streamwriter work
3. you do your changes on the array of strings in memory

Comment: I still don't think this fundamentally addresses the OP's performance problems.

Comment: @Kirk: The OP's performance problems is precisely due to the large number of reads and writes to disk he's doing. This directly addresses the very fundamentals of the OP's performance problems.

Comment: Since the OP is not actually writing to disk in his example, I don't see how this can be the case.

Comment: @Kirk: Read the OP's third paragraph. The given function is called from within a loop (30 times) and the return value of the function is written back to the file before calling the function again (which reopens the file).

Comment: @slebetman, Thanks for pointing that out.  Missed that after he posted the code.

Comment: @James: Your logic seems much relevant with my coding. I must ry yours one. I hope i be able to get out of my problem .If still i feel any difficulty then i will repost the query. Thanks for all the experts for their valuable comments.

Comment: @James: I have used the same logic as suggested by you, and now i am very pleased to say u thanks for giving me a very nice solution.Now i am not facing any problem of program loading/time consumtion. You are an expert. Thanks

Thanks for all other for having a healthy technical discussion!!

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = "blabla.hex";
StreamReader f1 = File.OpenText(fileName);
StreamWriter f2 = File.CreateText(fileName + ".temp_");

while (!f1.EndOfStream)
{
    String s = f1.ReadLine();
    //change the content of the variable 's' as you wish 
    f2.WriteLine(s);   
}

f1.Close();
f2.Close();
File.Replace(fileName + ".temp_", fileName, null);
```

Comment: Fellow,
The portion 
while (!f1.EndOfStream) 
{ 
    String s = f1.ReadLine(); 
    //change the content of the variable 's' as you wish  
    f2.WriteLine(s);    
} 
is quite same as i implemented, but the thing is , it takes long time in replacing 30 float values in  a 78kb hex file.
Hex file looks like,
:10700000418A57743BC5818E35478AC7AE9D9331FF
:10701000C0A5B9B13BF1593FB5E85EC92F103DD2CB
:107020003D7B08BDB849C5823251CD69AB8FC16D7A
:10703000B9A54DFF3484D605AE8D12CB27C6D349F2
:10704000C5181DA23FC677ACB9ADC42532D6AA1467
:1070500042A049B2BD1E8A80373E7673B080AB0B2A
.
.
.

Comment: And if i have to replace a float value(of 4 bytes) in a way such that 2 bytes lie in first line(as its last two bytes) and the other two bytes lie in the second line(as its first two bytes). then I have to be careful in reading and writing because the address for the float value is the same for all 4-bytes,except with a increment of 1 for eacch byte.

Comment: instead of looping over the lines 30 times, each pass replacing 1 float value, why not loop over the lines once, and replace all 30 float values during that single pass?  Am I missing something?